# Custom model manager for auth_user

Tags: django, django-models, django-managers

I want to include two extra managers on the auth `user` model, `active` and `inactive`, to give me just active, or just inactive users. This is how the model would look (even if the it is invalid):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ActiveManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(ActiveManager, self).get_query_set().filter(active=True)

class InactiveManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(InactiveManager, self).get_query_set().filter(active=False)

class User(models.Model):
    # user model...

    all_users = models.Manager()
    objects = ActiveManager()
    inactive = InactiveManager()
```

Where / how exactly would I place this so I can do a query such as `User.inactive.all()` ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need to use the `contribute_to_class` method on your Manager. Instead of the `User` class you have there, you will need something like this:

```
InactiveManager.contribute_to_class(User, 'inactive')
```

I suspect it doesn't matter exactly where you do this as long as it happens nice and early (before you use it!) - a models.py somewhere would feel vaguely right.